# Objective-C: declaring @protocol generates error Illegal interface qualifier

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols, nsobject, nsobjectprotocol

I'm trying to implement a @protocol/delegate but I'm getting this error:

`Illegal interface qualifier`

Here is my code:

```
//
//  MyProtocol.m
//  Apple-ObjC
//
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyProtoco : NSObject
@protocol SampleProtocolDelegate <NSObject>

@end
```

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error or how can I fix it?

I'll really appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: Don't do it between the &interface of `MyProtoco`. Do it above, also `@interface` needs a `@end` and `@protocol` too.

Answer (score 4):

You need to see the architecture of the file. You can't put `@protocol` like that between `@interface` and `@end`. Also, `@protocol` needs `@end` and so do `@interface`.

```
@protocol SampleProtocolDelegate <NSObject>
// Related to SampleProtocolDelegate
@end
@interface MyProtoco : NSObject
// Related to MyProtoco
@end
```

You can have various protocols/interface, you just need to put them one after the other. They are the the same "level" of declaration:

```
@protocol SampleProtocolDelegate <NSObject>
// Related to SampleProtocolDelegate
@end
@interface MyProtoco : NSObject
// Related to MyProtoco
@end   
@protocol SampleProtocolDelegate2 <NSObject>
// Related to SampleProtocolDelegate2
@end
@interface MyProtoco2 : NSObject
// Related to MyProtoco2
@end
@interface MyProtoco3 : NSObject
// Related to MyProtoco3
@end
@protocol SampleProtocolDelegate4 <NSObject>
// Related to SampleProtocolDelegate4
@end
@protocol SampleProtocolDelegate5 <NSObject>
// Related to SampleProtocolDelegate5
@end
```

With 2 protocols consecutive and two interfaces too to illustrate the "level".